ImageDatagenerator ()で左右にずらすと設定しても上下にずれてしまう
ニューラルネットワークについて勉強している初心者です。
ImageDataGenerator () について質問です。
以下のコードを実行すると、 datagen = ImageDataGenerator(width_shift_range=0.4) としているのに、画像が上下にずれてしまいます。お分かりの方教えて頂きたいです。 python==3.11.7 です。
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255
y_train = np.eye(10)[y_train.astype('int32').flatten()]

x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255
y_test = np.eye(10)[y_test.astype('int32').flatten()]

x_train, x_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(
    x_train, y_train, test_size=10000)

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(width_shift_range=0.4)

datagen.fit(x_train)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9, 15))
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, bottom=0,
                    top=0.5, hspace=0.05, wspace=0.05)

for x_batch, y_batch in datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=9, shuffle=False):
    for i in range(5):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 5, i + 1, xticks=[], yticks=[])
        ax.imshow(x_batch[i])
    break


明示的にheight_shift_range=0.0を指定してみてはどうでしょう？ Image Data Generatorの挙動の基礎 ちなみにこちら tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator によると非推奨: tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator は新しいコードには推奨されません。らしいですね。

ありがとうございます！ImageDataGeneratorの挙動から理解してみます。

「fig.とするとlots_adjust」の部分に日本語が混ざっています。本来のコードに修正できますか？　import文から記述されると第三者が検証しやすくなると思います。（ImageDataGenerator以外についても）

ご指摘ありがとうございます。編集致しました。
